# Adding aggregate fields to elixir graphql

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, graphql, absinthe

I am using absinthe with elixir (phoenix 1.3).  I have a blog app that has Users, Posts, and Likes, and the likes are joined with a many-to-many relationship between Users and Posts.

```
  schema "users" do
    field :email, :string
    field :handle, :string 
    many_to_many :liked_posts, MyApp.Content.Post, join_through: "likes"
  end

  schema "posts" do
    field :title, :string
    field :content, :string 
    many_to_many :liking_users, MyApp.Accounts.User, join_through: "likes"
  end

  schema "likes" do
    belongs_to :user, MyApp.Accounts.User
    belongs_to :post, MyApp.Content.Post
  end
```

Let's say I want to aggregate them on the backend rather than the front.  I would like `:liked_by` to simply be a count of all the likes that exist, more like `field :likes, :int`, so that I can get back responses like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "post" : {
      "title" : "Title",
      "content" : "This is the content",
      "likes" : 7
    }
  }
}
```

What would my object have to look like?  I want to do something like this:

```
  object :post do
    field :id, :integer
    field :title, :string
    field :content, :string
    field :likes, :integer, resolve: assoc(:liking_users, fn query, id, _ ->
       query |> from like in MyApp.Content.Like, where: like.post_id == ^id, select: count("*")
    )
  end
```

**EDIT #1:** More specifically, I'd like to know how to parameterize an anonymous function in the absinthe object.  I can get the object to return a non-parameterized value easily:

```
field :somenumber, :integer, resolve: fn (_,_) -> {:ok, 15} end
```

But adding a parameter like so

```
field :somenumber, :integer, resolve: fn (foo,_) -> {:ok, foo} end
```

returns the following:

```
...
"somenumber": {},
...
```

How can I pass in id of the object, or an implicitly associated query?

**EDIT #2:** I have found a solution to this, but it feels very hacky.

```
  object :post do
    field :id, :integer
    field :title, :string
    field :content, :string
    field :likes, :integer, resolve: fn (_,_,resolution) ->
      {:ok, Post.getLikeCount(resolution.source.id) }
    end
  end
```

Comment: `field :likes, :integer, resolve: &Post.get_likes/3` with a custom `Post.get_likes/3` implementation should do. See [`Absinthe.Schema.Notation.resolve`](https://hexdocs.pm/absinthe/Absinthe.Schema.Notation.html#resolve/1)  for details.

Comment: @mudasobwa Getting closer, see edit above

Comment: You do not need to use assoc, just put a function returning integer there. Also, assoc should likely work as well. Do you get any error or what?

Comment: Did you check the link I provided? I have no ability to check it now, but you might try the fun of arity 3 and IO.inspect what came as args from it.

Comment: @mudasobwa I found a hacky solution, see edit #2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After following @mudasobwa's advice, I have this solution:

```
 object :post do
    field :id, :integer
    field :title, :string
    field :content, :string
    field :likes, :integer, resolve: fn (query,_,_) ->
      Post.getLikeCount(query.id)
    end
  end
```

`resolution`, the third argument of the arity 3 anonymous function for the resolver, is an `Absinthe.Resolution` object. `resolution.source` is of type `MyApp.Content.Post`, of which `id` refers to that Post.

Then I just added a function into Post.ex called `getLikeCount/1` that gets the number of likes.

```
  def getLikeCount (post_id) do
    query =
      from l in MyApp.Content.Likes,
        where: l.post_id == ^post_id,
        select: count("*")

    case Repo.one(query) do
      nil -> {:error, "Error getting like count for post #{post_id}"}
      likes -> {:ok, likes}
    end
  end
```

Comment: [`Repo.one/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:one/2) would be probably more suitable here. Also, I don’t get why do you think this solution is hacky. BTW, according to the documentation, the first param in a call to resolver should be `Post.id`, isn’t it?

Comment: Updated.  Also it seems that the first variable in the arity 3 function contains exactly what I was looking for, so this no longer feels hacky.

Comment: looks like this would cause n+1 queries, wouldnt it be better to use dataloader or maybe batching so this query is not executed for every post returned?